# Making an Ubuntu VirtualBox VM the primary OS of my machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu OS in Virtual Box and did a lot of coding stuff there! now I want to make that my permanent OS. How can I get the bootable .iso file of my that virtual OS without losing my data?

Comment: Back up your data. Verify the backup matches the source. Repeat with another destination for the backup, and verify that. Only then can you consider moving the virtual OS to bare metal.

Answer (score 0):

With the default Virtualbox configuration this is possible, but a royal pain in the butt.  I'm going to say for a first-timer level of experience with Linux I don't advise this.

The easiest approach would be to back up /home to a USB device, write the ISO image to a different USB device with something like Rufus.  Install the OS with the second USB device, reinstall any software you added after the fact, and copy your files into your new /home directory from the first USB device.

To actually write your Ubuntu OS image to a physical disk most approaches are going to require you to have a separate disk.  Here's an example outline:

1. Buy a new SSD or HDD larger than your virtual disk and a USB adapter for it.
2. Boot some sort of USB Linux rescue disk in the VM, this can probably be done with just the ISO in the disk manager.
3. Connect the new disk to the system with the USB adapter and give the VM control of it.  This is a glitchy process in Virtualbox so you may need to disconnect and try multiple times.
4. Don't mount either the new drive or the disk image.
5. Use dd if=/dev/"sda or whatever the virtualbox disk is" of=/dev/"sdc or whatever the new disk is"
6. If feeling adventurous use fdisk to resize the last partition on the new disk to fill the remaining space and use resize2fs to get the filesystem to use the space.
7. Fix your new /etc/fstab if needed.
8. Power off and install the new disk in place of your old one.
9. Solve any UEFI secure boot problems.

Alternatively use Virtualbox's console tools to convert your disk image to VHD and use commercial Windows-compatible disk imaging software to write it to the new disk. Start at step 7/8.

Comment: actually, i know i can copy paste my code easily, but the thing that matters is the environment that is set up in virtual machine for ML.
i can copy the files bur installing all the libraries and their dependencies are the real headache I want to avoid :(

Comment: On a laptop I'd just recommend getting Guest additions running through DKMS and upping the allotment of resources allocated to the machine.  The loss of manufacturer drivers is often not worth it.  LXDE/LXQT and seamless mode make a nice combo.  
On a desktop you've got more options but be prepared for unanticipated problems.  For example I don't know if the UUID used by ubuntu in the fstab is part of the filesystem and would survive cloning to a real disk, or part of the device and would need to be modified for the new UUID after cloning.  Hence why you might need to fix the fstab.

Comment: Mostly what I'm saying is this is a "Mad Science Project".  This is not a normal operation people do very frequently with a solution built into the OS.  So you'll have to string together tools instead.  If you don't already have a half-baked plan then you will probably be learning the tools the whole way and it will not save you time over just reinstalling.  You'll learn a heck of a lot though.